# VSCode & Powershell: How to stop script and unregister object?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have a snippet that works fine. It registers an objectevent as follows (snippet):

```
Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
```

It works fine, but I can't seem to get the script to fully stop and unregister. When I use "normal" methods to stop code (listed below), when I rerun the code (via F5) I get error:

```
Register-ObjectEvent : Cannot subscribe to the specified event. A subscriber with the source identifier 'FileCreated' already exists.
```

The only way I can unregister it (so far) is to terminate the powershell.exe process, which also kills the powershell run time within VSCode (throwing errors, forcing a manual restart).

I start the code by hitting F5

To stop the code, I have tried:

- Shift-F5
- Ctrl-C (in the powershell terminal area)

Nothing works except as described above.

What am I missing?

Comment: You'll want to call `Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Where would this go?  In some finally block for the whole app?  (Where can I see an example of how to structure a "stay resident" script like this, so I can see where to put the exit cleanup?)

Answer (score 2):

***For debugging purposes only***, where you often force-stop your script, there are 2 options. Either run the `unregister-Event` line manually so the event is unregistered or do add something like that near the top f your script. (at least before the `Register-ObjectEvent` )

```
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -EA 0
```

`-EA 0` is the same as `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and will prevent the script from throwing an error when you are on a new session and the event was never registered yet.

**Note**: This should not be in your production script and is only meant as a debugging help. (If you want to keep it on hand, I'd say comment it out at least on the prod. version of the script)

Your production version of the script should implement `Unregister-Event` properly though, something more akin to:

```
$FileWatcherReg = @{
    InputObject      = $Watcher
    EventName        = 'Created'
    SourceIdentifier = 'FileCreated'
    MessageData      = @{WatchQueue = $WatchQueue; Timer = $WatchTimer }
    Action           = {
        if ($null -ne $event) {
            Write-Host "Path: $($Event.SourceArgs.FullPath) - ($($Event.Timegenerated))"
        }
    }
   
}

Register-ObjectEvent @FileWatcherReg 

while ($true) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100

    # Logic to exit the loop at some point.
}

# Exit script logic ...
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated
```

Comment: OK, I have two questions:  First, why should the unregister NOT be at the top of production code?  That looks really safe (to unregister prior to register) .   Second, I do not see where my script ever exits. It registers an event, the event has an action. That action stays loaded forever (until unregister or the PC shuts down). So I do not follow your suggestion.

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica It is not a big deal really but as a principle of good coding, it make no sense to have an unregister at the top of the script when the event was not registered. Debugging is the only context it make sense to have it there. Reallistically though, even if you put it there in prod., it won't really change much and if you need to debug it quite often, then you can leave it there...

Comment: Sage, in a script like this that registers an event, the script never exits, right? The script is an action that sits waiting to be fired. Where would an Unregister ever go?

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica I guess technically it doesn't matter. In the case of your script, since you register and never want to unregister, you can either omit it or include the unregister after the main loop. I personally like to include the unregister anyway so that if ever I modify the main loop to include an exit condition, I don't have to rethink about my resource cleanup because it is already there. In this particular case, it's not too much importrant. Anyhow, when debugging, that's annoying, hence the top of script suggestion.

Comment: Sage, I don't understand "main loop" in the context of an ObjectEvent. There is no loop... it is just a function hanging off an event...  (What am I missing?)

Comment: OK, I think I see an example that mirrors your example. I get it. But both of the examples, it seems to me, are a little too "scripty." Why should my script run forever? I want the action hanging off the event... and my script can just make that happen. There need not be a process running forever just so I can press Ctrl-C.... (I may be missing something...)  Here is the larger example: https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/using-filesystemwatcher-correctly-part-2#

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica  You either your Powershell process to stay open as long as you want to monitor so if you just want to monitor while a bunch of other stuff is happening, then it doesn't have to be infinite but as soon as your script is done, it will exit and monitoring will stop immediately. That's why usually you will often see some loop to keep the script running. The event handler need that otherwise it will be destroyed when your script terminate.

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica The example link you referenced though is nice since the Finally block of the Try / Catch work with CTRL + C so it would be perfect in a debugging context and also prod. I'll integrate that bit in my answer later today.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Sage's example above, is this larger example. It structures the event clearly, and shows how by keeping the script running, you can then cancel the script, which will trigger the cleanup block.

So there is something to be said for this approach. (However, I continue to see the whole Register-ObjectEvent as kind of a TSR... your code stays resident... forever... waiting for the relevant event....)

The example:
https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/using-filesystemwatcher-correctly-part-2#